# Auto layout issue using youtube-ios-player-helper and iOS 8

Tags: ios8, autolayout

Good afternoon, only one question, has anybody tried to use youtube-ios-player-helper library with iOS 8?

I'm having troubles with auto layout and YTPlayerView because the player not resize correctly

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because auto layout is trying to make up for the Scroll View Insets by adding the navigation header space at the top, so in order for this not to happen you can either check off the **"Adjust Scroll View Insets"** in your ViewController settings inside your story board or nib file, or thru code by calling **self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;** on your VC's viewDidLoad method. that's it :)

Comment: Thanks, gray space removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; only asnwer to remove gray space